# How can PPO be combined with HER?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, proximal-policy-optimization, hindsight-experience-replay

I ask because [PPO is apparently an on-policy algorithm](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/427140/is-proximal-policy-optimization-ppo-an-on-policy-reinforcement-learning-algori) & [the HER paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.01495.pdf) says that it can be combine with any **off-policy algorithm**. Yet I see [GitHub projects](https://github.com/SioKCronin/Hindsight-Experience-Replay) that have combined them somehow?

How is this done? And is it reasonable?